# Trouble while building Drake_last_sha_with_original_matlab Atlas with Bazel

Tags: bazel, drake

I have been attempting to build Drake project last from source with Bazel on Ubuntu 20.04 but the following error occurs when I run

```
bazel build :install
```

from the Atlas root directory:

```
dmitriy@dmitriy-Lenovo-ideapad-310-15ISK:~/git/drake2/drake-last_sha_with_original_matlab/drake/examples/Atlas$ bazel build :models
WARNING: The following rc files are no longer being read, please transfer their contents or import their path into one of the standard rc files:
/home/dmitriy/git/drake2/drake-last_sha_with_original_matlab/tools/bazel.rc
ERROR: Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/home/dmitriy/git/drake2/drake-last_sha_with_original_matlab/tools/third_party/kythe/tools/build_rules/config/pkg_config.bzl", line 176, column 42, in <toplevel>
        "build_file_template": attr.label(
Error in label: label() got unexpected keyword argument 'single_file'
ERROR: error loading package '': Extension file 'tools/third_party/kythe/tools/build_rules/config/pkg_config.bzl' has errors
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.119s
INFO: 0 processes.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (0 packages loaded)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last_sha_with_original_matlab branch is 7+ years old.  Are you *sure* that it's what you want to try to run?  Most people should not need to use it.  It's only useful for something like running examples from a paper published around that time.

The https://drake.mit.edu/release_notes/older_releases.html is the documentation related to this.

It will almost certainly not work on Ubuntu 20.04.  You'll need to use a virtual machine contemporaneous with the 7+ year age, so probably Ubuntu 14.04.

I'd also recommend just using the binaries https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/releases/tag/v0.9.11 instead of rebuilding it.

Comment: Thank you very much, the reason why I wanted to use this version: I wanted to try the implementation in matlab, since I have some problems with the current version